# ogr2ogr: Unable to import shapefile with '-lco RFC7946=YES' parameter to the PostGIS db

Tags: postgis, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to convert multipolygon to in the right-hand format so that Leaflet can use it on the front end.

```
ogr2ogr -nln [target_table] -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=gid -lco RFC7946=YES -lco PRECISION=NO Pg:"dbname=[taget_db] host=localhost user=spatial_user port=5432" source_sub_counties.shp
```

Import is done but there is warning:

> Warning 6: dataset Pg:dbname=[target_db} host=localhost
> user=spatial_user port=5432 does not support layer creation option
> RFC7946

How to fix this issue ?

Versions:

- GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27
- PostgresSQL version 14
- Ubuntu Linux 22/04

Answer (score 6):

The RFC7946=[YES/NO] option is a layer creation option of the GeoJSON driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html. Other drivers do not have that creation option, including the PostGIS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html.

In PostGIS the orientation of the rings can be controlled with the functions https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForcePolygonCCW.html and https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForcePolygonCW.html.
The "CCW" stands for counter-clockwise orientation of the exterior ring, and "CW" stands for clockwise orientation of the exterior ring.

Please clarify how do you plan to use the PostGIS data in Leaflet.

Comment: pool.query("SELECT id, ST_AsGeojson(geom)::json as polygon, name FROM public.table_name");

Comment: Frontend side : {subcounties && (<GeoJSON
                        key='my-geojson'
                        data={subcounties}
                        style={styles}
                        attribution='counties'
                    />)}

Comment: All this happens after ogr2ogr has done its job. See https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html about the PostGIS side, including the hint about using ST_ForcePolygonCCW if needed.